# Is there any alternative software for JSON Studio?

Tags: gratis, json, hadoop, mongodb

Is there any alternative software for [JSON Studio](http://jsonstudio.com/) that would be free to use or probably opensource? I have to use Jsonstudio for its interactivity handling json documents stored in MongoDb. It also easily interact with hadoop.

Will anybody give me some ideas where to look and start.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: @Izzy I need to handle JSON documents stored in mongodb. Building updating visualizing JSON data is what I meant for handling it.

Comment: Umer, I'm not a dev so this is not exactly my area of expertise. But what you describe sounds pretty broad. What exactly are the features you will need here? JSON handling (in which way?) certainly is not the only thing. There will be features like syntax highlighting, debugging, auto-complete, function-lookup, and more. And there's the OS (Windows? Mac? Linux?) it should run on. // Don't answer that in comments, better [edit] your question and add those details there. What about we expect, you can read in the article I've linked with my previous comment. Good luck!